# Pointer declaration

Tags: c, pointers

What does a pointer declaration like `char *(*a)[20];` mean? What is the difference with `char **a[20];`?

Are  both declarations equivalent? And if not, what is the distinction?

Comment: What is the difference between the pointer above and char **a[20]? I know this one because this is understandable:)

Comment: sample usage: `char *b[20];  a = &b;`

Answer (score 9):

That is a pointer to an array of pointers.

`char a[20];` is an array of characters.

`char* a[20];` is an array of pointers to characters

`char (*a)[20];` is a pointer to an array of characters

`char* (*a)[20];` is a pointer to an array of pointers to characters.

Note that `char** a[20]` is an array of pointers to pointers to characters. The brackets have higher precedence than the asterisk, so you need the parentheses to declare a pointer to an array.